# When I change any item in my layout, the inner layout that I have changed its measure programatically, returns to its first measure

Tags: android, layout, geometry, roulette-wheel-selection

I have a circle that i just one to show half of it in my page, and rotate. i pushed it up in code and its wok but any time that i want for example change the text of textviews or set its visibility in code it comes down again and if i want to push it up again the delay shows.
why its happen and how can i fix it?
or if you can suggest any other way i would be happy.

This is my xml Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background_blue"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">



    <com.aa.ccc.activities.CustomLinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/QuickPlayClipLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/clip_layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
    </com.aa.ccc.activities.CustomLinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_no_score"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            />



</RelativeLayout>
```

this is CustomLinearLayout class:

```
   public CustomLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        myContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
    {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec+((int)myContext.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.quickplay_offset)));
    }
```

and i set position of QuickPlayClipLayout in my code like this:

```
 @BindView(R.id.QuickPlayClipLayout)
    LinearLayout mainLayout;



    public static GameTestFragment newInstance() {
        GameTestFragment fragment = new GameTestFragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        mainLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mainLayout.layout(0, -(int) this.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.quickplay_offset),
                mainLayout.getWidth(), mainLayout.getHeight() + (int) this.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.quickplay_offset));

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for my problem.
in fact onmeaseure happens after oncreate and it was the cause of the delay.
i just put minus margin in CustomLinearLayout for pushing it up. and remove the code doing that function.

```
   <com.aa.ccc.activities.CustomLinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/QuickPlayClipLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="-95dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|top">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/clip_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
</com.aa.ccc.activities.CustomLinearLayout>
```